# How to write decryption code in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

To encode a string

Code:

```
public string base64Encode(string data)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] encData_byte = new byte[data.Length];
        encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);    
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
        return encodedData;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: creating the answer anew with even less information than the original is not really productive.

Comment: You might want to do something about the exception handling part. Now you are catching all exceptions and rethrowing a new one, which includes the original exception message. And you are resetting the stack trace this way. Besides nothing meaningfull is done to handle the exceptions.

Comment: Ah ... duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119561/help-me-throwing-exception-error-in-decoding-code-help-needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string Base64Decode(string data)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Convert.FromBase64String`.